# What are the exact requirements to unlock the IV checker NPC at the Battle Tree?

Tags: pokemon-sun-moon

He says

> This Pokémon...has relatively superior...
>   *ya-a-awn*
>   ...Who are you?
>   No one impressive enough to shock me awake.
>   *ya-a-awn*

And then refuses to check your Pokémon's IV's.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hatch 20 eggs using the Day Care, then go talk to the IV Judge at the Battle Tree. From then on, you can press a button in the PC to show a circular line graph that shows you each of your pokemon's IVs.

```
    Message     |  IV range
    No Good     |       0
    Decent      |  1 - 15
    Pretty Good | 16 - 25
    Very Good   | 26 - 29
    Fantastic   |      30
    Best        |      31
```